# Comparing input from Scanner with key and value from HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm creating an app in which I need to create account and log into first.
I thought that I can use HashMap for it, where login is my key and password is my value.

Unfortunately, I've got problem with log into account that I've created.

Here is class with methods that take responsible for log. There is problem with `checkIfLoginDataIsIncorrect`

```
void inputLoginAndPassword() {
    System.out.println("Input your login");
    login = input.next();

    System.out.println("Input your password");
    password = input.next();
}

boolean checkIfLoginDataIsIncorrect() {
    if (loginDetails.containsKey(login)                                    
        && loginDetails.get(login).equals(password)) {
        System.out.println("You've logged in.");
        return false;
    }
    else
        System.err.println("Bad login or password");
    return true;
}
```

**Main.java:**

```
AccountMaker accountMaker = new AccountMaker();
AccountLogger accountLogger = new AccountLogger();
//I'VE WRITTEN IT JUST FOR CHECK:
HashMap<String, String> loginDetails = accountMaker.getLoginDetails();
loginDetails.put("lala","papa");

[...]

    case 2:
        while (loopIsTrue) {
            accountLogger.inputLoginAndPassword();
            if(!accountLogger.checkIfLoginDataIsIncorrect()) {
                loopIsTrue = false;
            } else {
                loopIsTrue = true;
            }
        }
        break;
```

**AccountMaker.java:**

```
public class AccountMaker {
    private HashMap<String, String> loginDetails = new HashMap<>();
    private String login, password;
    private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    [...]

    HashMap<String, String> getLoginDetails() {
        return loginDetails;
    }
}
```

**AccountLogger.java:**

```
public class AccountLogger {
    private AccountMaker accountMaker = new AccountMaker();
    private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    private HashMap<String, String> loginDetails = accountMaker.getLoginDetails();
    private String login, password;

    void inputLoginAndPassword() {
        System.out.println("Input your login");
        login = input.next();

        System.out.println("Input your password");
        password = input.next();
    }

    boolean checkIfLoginDataIsIncorrect() {
        //I'VE WRITTEN IT JUST FOR CHECK
        System.out.println(login);
        System.out.println(password);
        ///
        if (loginDetails.containsKey(login) && loginDetails.get(login).equals(password)) {
            System.out.println("You've logged in.");
            return false;
        }
        else
            System.err.println("Bad login or password");
        return true;
    }
}
```

For example, if I write `loginDetails.put("lala","papa");` and then I want to log into this acc program says `Bad login or password`.

Comment: probably, you did something wrong. have you debugged your code, and checked whether the values are what you think they are? also: keep your code simpler, that makes it easier to read. you are writing five lines of code, where one suffices, simpler is better in such things

Comment: You may want to show all the relevant bits, like the HashMap declaration.  Try printing what `login` and `password` are, so you can see if they match what you expect.  Unrelated, your if/else statements feel a bit weird, but not functionally incorrect.  It may be cleaner to remove `else` in your checking method, and to use `loopIsTrue = accountLogger.checkIfLoginDataIsIncorrect();`

Comment: In case this is for a real world application, you should never store passwords in clear. Instead store a hash and compare the hashed user input with the stored value.

Comment: Hey @phflack @Stultuske, thanks for answer. I've written two lines of code in ```checkIfLoginDataIsIncorrect```: ```System.out.println(login);```    and   ```System.out.println(password);``` And it printed the same login and password that I've inputed. I don't know where should I look further.

Comment: @Henry Actually, I'm learning Java :P Don't know much things yet.

Comment: Do you call `loginDetails.put("lala", "papa");` before or after you attempt to login?  Posting that bit of code may be useful

Comment: @phflack I called it at the beggining of Main Class, so before attempt to login. I think that it might be hard to read lines here. So here is link to this class on github: https://github.com/must1/ToDoApp/blob/master/Main.java On 13 line I've added ```loginDetails.put("lala", "papa");```. On 28 line we've got what we are talking.

Comment: @phflack Thanks for editing my post.I will know how next post should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're running into is you're polling the wrong `HashMap`

- Create `AccountMaker`

  - The `AccountMaker` makes a new `HashMap`
- Create 'AccountLogger'

  - The `AccountLogger` makes a new `AccountMaker`

    - The `AccountMaker` makes a new `HashMap`

We end up with two different instances of `AccountMaker`, and their different `HashMaps`

---

Try using the same `AccountMaker` that your `AccountLogger` uses, or pass it to the constructor

**Using constructor:**

```
//Main.java
AccountMaker accountMaker = new AccountMaker();
AccountLogger accountLogger = new AccountLogger(accountMaker);

//AccountLogger.java
class AccountLogger
{
    private AccountMaker accountMaker;

    public AccountLogger(AccountMaker maker)
    {
        accountMaker = maker;
    }
}
```

**Getting the same `AccountMaker`:**

```
//Main.java
AccountLogger accountLogger = new AccountLogger();
AccountMaker accountMaker = accountLogger.getAccountMaker();

//AccountLogger.java
public AccountMaker getAccountMaker()
{
    return accountMaker;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why I'm calling two different `HashMaps`. In `AccountMaker` I created new instance of `HashMap` and I created `getter` to it. Thought that by writing `HashMap<String, String> loginDetails = accountMaker.getLoginDetails();` I use the same map.

Comment: @must That's the `HashMap` from `accountMaker`, but when you use `accountLogger` to try and log in, it has a different `AccountMaker` which is private (... which has its own `HashMap` as well)

Comment: Meh... It works :D Just it really weird for me. Don't understand for 100% why I had to do this. Could you tell me about what should I read to understand it more? Right now, Java makes me headache:P

Comment: @must I would recommend following the trail and seeing where new objects are created, it may also be a good idea to post this on code review, you could probably get a lot of suggestions on how to improve it _(ie passing in values to methods like user/pass, instead of trying to make the class read it, store it in a class variable, and then use it)_

Comment: yeah, I will post it after I end everything. Thanks for help ;)!

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to understand your problem and have written below sample program to meet your requirement. Compare your code and see if you can fix your issue. If not, can you modify below code and let me know where it is failing.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Testlogin {
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
static Map<String, String> loginDetails = new HashMap<String, String>();
static String login,password;


static void inputLoginAndPassword() {
    System.out.println("Input your login");
   login = input.next();

    System.out.println("Input your password");
    password = input.next();
}

boolean checkIfLoginDataIsIncorrect() {
    if (loginDetails.containsKey(login)                                    
        && loginDetails.get(login).equals(password)) {
        System.out.println("You've logged in.");
        return false;
    }
    else
        System.err.println("Bad login or password");
    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    loginDetails.put("lala", "papa");
    inputLoginAndPassword();
    boolean loopIsTrue =true;
    Testlogin testlogin = new Testlogin();
    while (loopIsTrue) {
       // Testlogin.inputLoginAndPassword();
        System.out.println("You have entered login = "+login);
        System.out.println("You have entered password = "+password);
        if(!testlogin.checkIfLoginDataIsIncorrect()) {
              loopIsTrue = false;
        } else {
                inputLoginAndPassword(); // bad login detected so asking for correct details again.
                loopIsTrue = true;
              //
        }
      }
      //break;
}
```

}

Comment: Nah, the only difference is that you've got static variables and I've got private. Here is my Github, with these classes. If you've got time, you can take a look, becuase it's really strange. https://github.com/must1/ToDoApp

Comment: If I paste: ```System.out.println("You have entered login = "+login);
        System.out.println("You have entered password = "+password)``` it is giving correct login and password.

Comment: @must I found the root cause after looking into your code on Github, you are actually using two different Hashmap instances (Although you have same name, i.e loginDetails). In main class you have one entry in loginDetails Hashmap  (loginDetails.put("lala","papa");) but when it comes to loginDetails Hashmap  in AccountLogger, it is empty map. No records are present inside it. You are comparing {lala,papa} with empty map, so it will never enters true login case.

Comment: I don't understand how can I have two Hashmap instances when I've got the same line of code: `HashMap<String, String> loginDetails = accountMaker.getLoginDetails();` and it is comparing with the same `getter`. How can i reapair this?

Comment: change if condition in Main:                                                                     if (!accountLogger.checkIfLoginDataIsIncorrect(loginDetails)) {
                                    loopIsTrue = accountLogger.checkIfLoginDataIsIncorrect(loginDetails);
                                } 
And also, change checkIfLoginDataIsIncorrect to:
 boolean checkIfLoginDataIsIncorrect(HashMap<String, String> loginDetails2) {
     //  Here we are assigning loginDetails of Accountlogger =loginDetails //from Main cls.
        loginDetails = loginDetails2  ;
       <keep samecode>
     }

Comment: yeee. Actually, @phflack helped me. Don't understand for 100%, but I will try to make it right. :P Thank you too for improve my skills :)